# Which Author Should Receive Earliest Credit for Cyberpunk Literary Genre?

Tags: history-of, cyberpunk

Author William Gibson is often credited with creating the cyberpunk genre characterized by a dystopian future and a technology heavy society.

He receives this distinction primarily due to popularity of two of his works *Johnny Mnemonic* published in 1981 (one year prior to *Blade Runner* being released at the theater), and Neuromancer published in 1984.

Phillip K. Dick wrote *Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep* in 1968.

The term “cyberpunk” itself appears to have been coined by author Bruce Bethke in his 1980 short story, ultimately published in Amazing Stories in 1983.

Is Gibson’s popular credit as fathering the “cyberpunk” genre more a function of being in right place at right time with his most popular prose book-ending some important progressions.

Can another author be recognized as originating the cyberpunk genre, or originating the elements that have come to define the genre, and when?

Comment: Thanks; it refers to enough earlier examples to be candidates.

Comment: I hope one of them was "The Girl Who Was Plugged IN" by James Tiptree Jr. That's a good one.